# TypeError: cfg.getTemplate is not a function

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router

I am currently working on web app with angularjs. My files are bundled using Webpack. Dependencies are:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.5.7",
"angular-animate": "^1.5.8",
"angular-cookies": "^1.5.7",
"angular-img-http-src": "^1.0.1",
"angular-jwt": "0.0.9",
"angular-messages": "^1.5.7",
"angular-ui-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
"angular-ui-router": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
"jquery": "^2.1.4",
"bootstrap-material-design": "^0.5.10"
```

I got stuck with error:[Errors in chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xiu4g.png)

I am adding the code repository:

https://github.com/markrudenkov/forecast-forex-rates/tree/master/src/main/app

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error here (Webpack2, AngularJS). It's an issue with ui-router though.

There is [a patch](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/3410/files) that works fine in my case (so far :-)), but I can't judge if it's ok or just masking a real problem.

There is also a [ticket](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3275) that seems to cover the same issue.